# Strange issue in chrome with keyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, onkeyup

I am creating timpicker plugin, here is what i have so far.

**HTML**

```
 <input id="txtTime"/>
```

**jQuery:**

```
 function formatTime(s) {
        return s.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/^(\d\d)(\d\d).*$/, "$1:$2")
    }

    (function ($) {
        $.fn.timeInput = function () {
            return $(this).keyup(function () {
                $(this).val(formatTime($(this).val()))
            });
        }
    })(jQuery);

    $("#txtTime").timeInput()
```

**Problem:** I am using chrome 28 and in that Cursor always goes to the end of text. if i use `change()`, it works fine. Can anybody help me to resolve this issue? or why this is happening? in firefox it works fine.

### Fiddle Demo

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: The cursor jumps to the end because you're programmatically setting the value of the input.  See this question....

Comment: To fix the issue, only run your formatting code on blur or change.

Comment: @Archer  Why it's working in Firefox?

Comment: Because of how Firefox handles the setting of data in input boxes.  If you can tell all your users to use Firefox, then there's no problem, otherwise you need a fix ;)